# Strange behavior of WPF app accessing Web API

Tags: c#, wpf, api

I have a WPF app which I use it to pull data from a Web API.

After login I store the token and based on that you can access the API or not.

Case 1: Login, get token, click button to get data:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    getMovies();
}
```

Method implemented

```
private void getMovies()
{
    var accessToken = token;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5001/movies/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("get").Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Movies not Found");
    }
}
```

And I receive back a 401.

Case 2: I call the API from the Start method (same code as above): get data from API

```
public async void Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    getMovies();
}
```

How is this possible? And how can I do to access my API outside of the `Start` method?

Comment: You are right, I just edit my post with latest version of my code.

Comment: Ok lets us see if we can narrow down what the actual problem is and work from there as the question is still a little confusing in its current state.

Comment: is the same token used for both calls?

Comment: Yes, I checked that and is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method should first be refactored to follow commonly suggested syntax

```
string baseUrl = "http://localhost:5001/movies/"

private async Task getMoviesAsync() {
    var accessToken = token; //assuming token is being retrieved and set somewhere else
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
        .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var response = await client.GetAsync("get");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        MessageBox.Show( await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Movies not Found");
    }
}
```

and called as follows

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    await getMoviesAsync();
}
```

Creating `HttpClient` on ever call is usually not advised but that is off-topic for the current problem at hand.

Comment: Thank you! I a still new to desktop apps but your answer solved my question.